# React Native/API - onPress returns all links in API instead of the link relevant to the item being pressed

Tags: javascript, react-native, api, jsx, hook

Apologies, couldn't figure out a straightforward way to title this, so thanks in advance.

I am tasked with creating a page of links supplied by an API I made that connects to a CMS. The screen gathers the below data to be viewed on the screen:

```
Title,
Content
```

These items, along with a URL live within a "Resource". The URL is not visible to the user, but it is grouped with its own Title and Content.

Currently things show correctly on the screen, but when trying to connect the URL to the Resource, I'm unable to have the page navigate correctly. When I console.log(thing-I'm-returning), it sends me back all URLs for all Resources, and if the private browser opens to a web page, it might open to any in the list. This happens when I press any of the Resources.

Code below (first time posting, I'm fully desperate. Let me know if this looks like trash and I'll correct however is ideal).

```
const { resourceData } = useResourceContent(binding);

const resourceList = resourceData?.Resources?.map((r, i) => ({
    id: i.toString(),
    title: r.Title,
    url: r.Url,
    content: r.Content,
  }));

 const resourceDetails = resourceData?.Resources;
 const { openUrl } = useWebBrowser();
 const { resourceData } = useResourceContent(binding);

 const resourceDetails = resourceData?.Resources;

  const urlList = [];
  const handleOpenSite = () => {
    resourceDetails?.map((r, i) => 
     {if (resourceDetails !== undefined && resourceDetails) {
        urlList.push(r.Url);
      }

      console.log(urlList[i]); //let's say there are 2 resources, each with their own website. This will return both websites no matter what resource I select

//the below is required, as a private browser is required
      return openUrl(urlList[i]);
    });
  };
```

```
API looks something like:
[{"Content": "Test. ", "Url": "https://instagram.com", "Title": "blah blah blah"}, 
{{"Content": "Test2.", "Url": "https://google.com.com", "Title": "blah blah blah"},]
```

Here's the View, though I'm unsure if it's necessary here.

```
<View>
        <ResourceNavigationList
          onPress={handleOpenSite}
          small
          listItems={resourceList}
          backgroundColor="transparent"
        />
</View>
```

And here's the ResourceNavigationList component, which is likely the issue since it's a little bit nonsense.:

```
const ResourceNavigationList = ({
  listItems,
  backgroundColor,
  small,
  reverse,
  onPress,
}) => {
  const { ct } = useCountryTranslation();
  const colorScheme = useColorScheme();
  const bgColor = backgroundColor || Colors[colorScheme].altBackground;
  const { openUrl } = useWebBrowser();

  const renderItem = ({ item, rUrl }) => {
    const handleOnPress = () => {
      if (item) {
        openUrl(rUrl).toString();
        console.log("WHY AREN'T YOU OPENING?");
      }
    };

    return (
      <ResourceNavigationListItem
        key={key}
        reverse={reverse}
        small={small}
        item={item}
        // url={rUrl}
        onPress={onPress}
      />
    );
  };

  return (
    <FlatList
      renderItem={renderItem}
      data={listItems}
      keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
      style={{
        paddingVertical: 20,
        backgroundColor: bgColor,
      }}
    />
  );
};

ResourceNavigationList.propTypes = {
  listItems: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
  backgroundColor: PropTypes.string,
  small: PropTypes.bool,
  reverse: PropTypes.bool,
  onPress: PropTypes.func,
};

export default ResourceNavigationList;
```

Finally, here's the ResourceNavigationListItem

```
const ResourceNavigationListItem = ({ item, onPress, style, small }) => {
  const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    //styling is here, but leaving it off because it isn't relevant and took up a lot of space
  });

  return (
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={onPress} style={[styles.item, style]}>
      <View style={styles.title}>
        <Icon style={styles.linkArrow} size={16} icon={faExternalLink} />
      </View>
      <View style={styles.title}>
        <Text style={styles.titleText}>
          {item.title ? decode(item.title) : item.title}
        </Text>
      </View>
      <View style={styles.title}>
        <Text style={styles.titleText}>
          {item.content ? decode(item.content) : item.content}
        </Text>
      </View>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
};

ResourceNavigationListItem.propTypes = {
  item: PropTypes.shape({
    icon: PropTypes.object,
    title: PropTypes.string,
    content: PropTypes.string,
  }).isRequired,
  onPress: PropTypes.func,
  style: PropTypes.object,
  small: PropTypes.bool,
};

export default ResourceNavigationListItem;
```

Thanks so very much.

I've tried mapping and for-looping. I've tried applying the mapping directly to the component. These have gleaned me the most success. Most everything else I've tried didn't return anything at all, or returned everything many times.

I've been struggling for a few days and have found lots of solutions similar to my problem within stackoverflow, but nothing fully relevant/recent (I'm fairly newb with regard to backend tingz). If y'all happen upon something I missed, please be kind, and if you'd be down to help me, I'd be so very grateful.

Comment: Can you show us the code for the ResourceNavigationList component?

Comment: Added to the post. Also, your solution worked, but adding in the event someone else stumbles upon this. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took a look and I think this has to do with confusion regarding the props hierarchy within your example.

Right now you are passing `onPress` down from the parent of `ResourceNavigationList`:

- Parent > onPress

  - ResourceNavigationList

    - ResourceNavigationListItem

While there is nothing inherently incorrect about the parent owning the `onPress` function, you have everything you need to perform the desired `onPress` functionality within the `ResourceNavigationList` component. It looks like you were almost there with your `handleOnPress` function.

Based on the data contract you provided, it looks like you should be able to do this:

```js
const ResourceNavigationList = ({
  listItems,
  backgroundColor,
  small,
  reverse,
  onPress,
}) => {
  const {
    ct
  } = useCountryTranslation();
  const colorScheme = useColorScheme();
  const bgColor = backgroundColor || Colors[colorScheme].altBackground;
  const {
    openUrl
  } = useWebBrowser();

  const renderItem = ({
    item,
    rUrl
  }) => {
    const handleOnPress = () => {
      if (item && item ? .Url) {
        openUrl(item ? .Url);

        // If you do need to perform additional logic controlled
        // by the parent component, you can add a quick line to 
        // execute the onPress function if it has been provided.
        if (onPress) onPress(item);
      }
    };

    return ( <
      ResourceNavigationListItem key = {
        key
      }
      reverse = {
        reverse
      }
      small = {
        small
      }
      item = {
        item
      }
      onPress = {
        onPress
      }
      />
    );
  };

  return ( <
    FlatList renderItem = {
      renderItem
    }
    data = {
      listItems
    }
    keyExtractor = {
      (item) => item.id
    }
    style = {
      {
        paddingVertical: 20,
        backgroundColor: bgColor,
      }
    }
    />
  );
};

ResourceNavigationList.propTypes = {
  listItems: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
  backgroundColor: PropTypes.string,
  small: PropTypes.bool,
  reverse: PropTypes.bool,
  onPress: PropTypes.func,
};

export default ResourceNavigationList;
```

Comment: Thanks @max-morrow, worked like a charm! Please enjoy this internet point, complimentary with your stay.